# CRM 2011 Microsoft's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

We're using CRM 2011 here. We just upgraded all our JavaScript to use XRM vs. CRM. While doing some testing of our JavaScript, we discovered a defect. Namely, when we change a value in a drop-down field, we get this error in the form of an Alert:

---

There was an error with this field's customized event.

Field:accessmode

Event:onchange

Error:'systemUserForm' is undefined

---

The problem is, that JavaScript is not ours. Via the developer tools, it appears to be Microsoft's JavaScript, probably dynamically generated. Selecting the new value does change it, but the code seems to want to operate on a `DependentPicklist` based on the selected value. Of course, it never executes because of the error.

Here is the code is crashes on (my line numbers):

```
1  Type.registerNamespace("Mscrm");
2  Mscrm.accessmode_onchange = function () {
3     paramParentFieldId = "accessmode";
4     paramChildFieldId = "caltype";
5     for (var depPickList in systemUserForm.gArrDependentPicklists) {
```

It throws the error on line 4, but the error indicates the error is actually with line 5.

My question is, how can we fix Microsoft's dynamically generated JavaScript?

Comment: This sounds like a (CRM4?) variation of the CRM SDKs [code sample for dependent OptionSets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594433(v=crm.5).aspx). Maybe you can simply replace yours with the one from the SDK.

Comment: Are you sure, there is not custom javascript on onchange event, that may be causing error,
try disabling all the custom js on form and try again,

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @Dot_NETPro: We're sure it's not our JavaScript because CRM let's us see all the JavaScript the page uses. Furthermore, with browser developer tools, we can see the JavaScript that is causing the error and even step through it. The snippet in the question is definitely not by us; it's something automatically added by CRM.

This question is now moot. The users say they've never seen it and almost never use the option that causes it. Also, we're upgrading to CRM 2016 soon and it may not be present in that version of the software.

Comment: Some custom Javascript functions that you add in the Ribbon Customizations appears as CRM code, because it is added dynamically to an aspx page, and you see it as that aspx file in the Developer Tools.
I'd do as @Dot_NETPro suggest and disable also all the ribbon customizations in that form.